# Get multiple lines from a single table and insert into another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert data from a table into another table. It has to be only one row or multiple rows depending on the input parameters.

Here is an example

The table with the original rows

```
ID  |  PATTERNID
----+-----------
1   |  1
2   |  1
3   |  1
4   |  1
5   |  2
6   |  3
7   |  3
8   |  3
```

There can be multiple ID for one pattern.

And I need to insert data into another table with the pattern ID.

I trying to do a stored procedure in which i just have to pass the patternID as a parameter. I would like to make inserts into another table.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: What would the desired output look like here?

Comment: Approximatively the same as the original ! i just want to decide what pattern i want to insert in my new table !

Comment: Single row insert of multiple rows? Like....a comma seperated list? STUFF() and FOR XML() will solve this

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you...

```
/*
-- create temp tables for test

CREATE TABLE #SourceTable
(
    ID INT
  , PATTERNID INT
);


CREATE TABLE #TargetTable
(
    ID INT
  , PATTERNID INT
);

INSERT INTO #SourceTable (ID, PATTERNID) VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO #SourceTable (ID, PATTERNID) VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT INTO #SourceTable (ID, PATTERNID) VALUES (3, 1)
INSERT INTO #SourceTable (ID, PATTERNID) VALUES (4, 1)
INSERT INTO #SourceTable (ID, PATTERNID) VALUES (5, 2)
INSERT INTO #SourceTable (ID, PATTERNID) VALUES (6, 3)
INSERT INTO #SourceTable (ID, PATTERNID) VALUES (7, 3)
INSERT INTO #SourceTable (ID, PATTERNID) VALUES (8, 3)

*/

DELETE FROM #TargetTable

DECLARE @ParamValue INT;

SET @ParamValue = 2;

INSERT INTO #TargetTable
(
    ID
  , PATTERNID
)
SELECT ID, PATTERNID FROM #SourceTable
WHERE PATTERNID = @ParamValue

SELECT * FROM #TargetTable
```

Noel